# iPhone:How to send an image from one view to another view fetched from photo library using NSUserDefault?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have successfully fetched an image from photo library and I have set it on the button but now I want to send this image in another view then how can I send this image using NSUserDefault

plz provide code if you have.

thanx in advance...

Comment: You should not use NSUserDefaults to send data between objects.

Comment: you can set thet on an imageview use image object and pass

Comment: You can convert your image into NSData and placed in UserDefaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass this image object while pushing from one view to another....Consider "imageToPass" be your UIImage object.Use this code in the FirstViewController.m, button action:

```
NextViewController *nextView=[[NextViewController alloc]init];
[nextView initialiseWithImage:imageToPass] ;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
[nextView release];
```

In "NextViewController.m" use the below code:

```
-(void)initialiseWithImage:(UIImage*)image{


//Use the "image".`enter code here`


}
```

or you can take directly from NSUserDefault from the NextViewController also.

Comment: What do you mean by "or you can take directly from NSUserDefault from the NextViewController also"?

Comment: We cannot use NSUserDefault for sending data  to another view...i mean that if the image is stored in Userdefaults he can retrieve it from the NextViewController directly.

Comment: That's very true Praveen.
just need to Have UIImage(suppose imageName) instance variable in NextViewController class with property and synthesized .
Now Just replace the [nextView initialiseWithImage:imageToPass] ;with Line nextView.imageName=imageToPass ;

Comment: we can't store image in NSUserDefault

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the above code of NSuser default, But the problem regarding NSUserDefault is that it always stores the value . you have to implement condition according to it. and make it nil after uses.

Answer (score -1):

```
Use Below Code It's Easy to use

-(void)storeImageNSDefaults{
//here stored images in NSUserDefaults.
//where imageName is image named.
NSData* imgData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageName);
[[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults] setObject:imgData forKey:@"image"];
[[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}

 //getImage from Nsusedefaults 
 // in other ViewController
-(void)showImage{
NSData* image=[[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"image"];
UIImage* img=[UIImage imageWithData:image];
//now you can use that img image on any imageview
}

It'll Definitely Work

But i'll suggest you use the praveen's code with one change.

nextView.imageName=imageToPass
in place of [nextView initialiseWithImage:imageToPass] ;
```

Comment: No. No. No. No. No. Do NOT use NSUserDefaults for transferring data between methods in objects or for transferring data between classes. NSUserDefaults is for persisting small amounts of data that will be needed the next time an app is started. It may "definitely work", but there is a difference between working code and good code.

Comment: hello Nick i'll agree with you. But how can you say using NSUserDefaults we can not achieve the desired result.it's depend on the way of using the NSuserdefaults(programming) .if we remove the object For corresponding key as the ViewController(and NextViewController has used the ImageData from NSUserDefaulst) class load.It'll work fine.so just read the question and answer both carefully before making any vote.

Comment: Just because the question was asked doesn't mean it should be answered literally. The question says that he wants to "send this image in another view". Answering questions on SO is for educating people. If we just blindly answer the question, then how are people going to learn? Better to explain the "correct" method and point out reasons why the suggested solution is not good. This way people will grow their skillset and knowledge. If you only have a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.

Comment: I am saying you same.just view the answer.

Comment: Not So,I had edited my question very early.
but you have not seen that changes.

Comment: This isn't the place for an argument. You edited your post to add the comment about using other code 58 minutes ago. I posted my comment 1 hour ago (ie BEFORE you edited it). This question has been answered and the answer accepted. There's no value in continuing this now.